# How to set TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ in a postgresql function?

Tags: postgresql

Literlly, Is it possible to `set transaction isolation level` to `REPEATABLE READ`.

My function seems like below...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function()
RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;

  PERFORM now();

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Result of function call

```
ERROR:  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL must be called before any query
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ"
PL/pgSQL function my_function() line 3 at SET
```

Is it true that postgresql does not support `repeatable read` in a function?

Comment: The query that called the function is executed in the same transaction. You cannot change the transaction isolation if the transaction has already started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `PostgreSQL` you cannot set transaction isolation in a function.

Instead, you can/should set the transaction before calling your function.

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;

-- call your function...

COMMIT;
```